# Windows API CreateDialog: Modeless Dialog just not show up

Tags: windows, winapi, user-interface, window

I really can't figure out how to make a modeless dialog box even after googling extensively.
What I want to do is to trigger a dialog box by pressing a button on main window.

(So let me put the whole stuff here. I haven't put the whole stuff up before lest it is too messy to read.)

My code is as followed:

```
#include "main.h"
#include "resource.h"
 #include <tchar.h>

INT_PTR CALLBACK AboutDlgProc(HWND hwnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
switch(Message)
{
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
    return TRUE;
    break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch(LOWORD(wParam))
        {
            case IDOK:
                EndDialog(hwnd, IDOK);
            break;
            case IDCANCEL:
                EndDialog(hwnd, IDCANCEL);
            break;
        }
    break;
    default:
        return FALSE;
}
return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK MainWinProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
switch(uMsg)
{
case WM_COMMAND:
    switch(LOWORD(wParam))
    {
    case ID_FILE_EXIT:
        SendMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, NULL, NULL);
        break;
    case LAUNCH_CONSOLE:
        HWND aDiag = CreateDialog((HINSTANCE) GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), hwnd, (DLGPROC) AboutDlgProc);
        if(aDiag == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(hwnd, TEXT("Error"), TEXT("Error"), MB_OK);
        DWORD dwLE = GetLastError();
        TCHAR szLE[16];
        _ltoa_s(dwLE, szLE, 10 );
        MessageBox(hwnd, szLE, TEXT("Error"), MB_OK); 
    }
        ShowWindow(aDiag, SW_SHOW);
        break;
    }
    break;
case WM_CLOSE:
    DestroyWindow(hwnd);
    break;
case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
default:
    break;
}
return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

int CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
WNDCLASS mainWindowClass = {};
mainWindowClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
mainWindowClass.lpfnWndProc = MainWinProc;
mainWindowClass.hInstance = hInstance;
mainWindowClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) COLOR_WINDOW;
mainWindowClass.lpszMenuName = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MENU1);
mainWindowClass.lpszClassName = TEXT("MainWindow");

RegisterClass(&mainWindowClass);
LONG units = GetDialogBaseUnits();
HWND aWindow = CreateWindow(TEXT("MainWindow"), TEXT("Briancheung"), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
HWND aButton = CreateWindow("BUTTON", TEXT("Try"), WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON, 100, 100, 50, 50, aWindow, (HMENU) LAUNCH_CONSOLE, hInstance, NULL);
ShowWindow(aWindow, SW_NORMAL);
MSG aMsg = {};
while(GetMessage(&aMsg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&aMsg);
    DispatchMessage(&aMsg);
}

return 0;
}
```

My resource template is VS2012 generated:

```
// Microsoft Visual C++ generated resource script.
//
#include "resource.h"

#define APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 2 resource.
//
#include "afxres.h"

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#undef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Chinese (Simplified, PRC) resources

#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_CHS)
LANGUAGE LANG_CHINESE, SUBLANG_CHINESE_SIMPLIFIED

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// TEXTINCLUDE
//

1 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
"resource.h\0"
END

2 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
"#include ""afxres.h""\r\n"
"\0"
END

3 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
"\r\n"
"\0"
END

#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED

#endif    // Chinese (Simplified, PRC) resources
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Chinese (Traditional, Hong Kong S.A.R.) resources

#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_ZHH)
LANGUAGE LANG_CHINESE, SUBLANG_CHINESE_HONGKONG

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Menu
//

IDR_MENU1 MENU
BEGIN
POPUP "File"
BEGIN
    MENUITEM "New",                         ID_FILE_NEW40001
    MENUITEM "Open",                        ID_FILE_OPEN40002
    MENUITEM SEPARATOR
    MENUITEM "Save",                        ID_FILE_SAVE40003
    MENUITEM "Save As",                     ID_FILE_SAVEAS
    MENUITEM SEPARATOR
    MENUITEM "Exit",                        ID_FILE_EXIT
END
POPUP "View"
BEGIN
    MENUITEM "Properties",                  ID_VIEW_PROPERTIES
END
POPUP "Help"
BEGIN
    MENUITEM "About",                       ID_HELP_ABOUT
END
END


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Dialog
//

IDD_DIALOG1 DIALOGEX 0, 0, 309, 90
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "Dialog"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK",IDOK,198,69,50,14
PUSHBUTTON      "Cancel",IDCANCEL,252,69,50,14
CONTROL         "",IDC_OCX1,"{6BF52A52-394A-11D3-B153-00C04F79FAA6}",WS_TABSTOP,23,24,259,25
END


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// DESIGNINFO
//

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
GUIDELINES DESIGNINFO
BEGIN
IDD_DIALOG1, DIALOG
BEGIN
    LEFTMARGIN, 7
    RIGHTMARGIN, 302
    TOPMARGIN, 7
    BOTTOMMARGIN, 83
END
END
#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Dialog Info
//

IDD_DIALOG1 DLGINIT
BEGIN
IDC_OCX1, 0x376, 166, 0
0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0300, 0x0000, 0x0008, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0005, 0x0000, 
0x0000, 0x0000, 0x3ff0, 0x0003, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0005, 0x0000, 0x0000, 
0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0008, 0x0002, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0003, 0x0001, 0x0000, 
0x000b, 0xffff, 0x0003, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x000b, 0xffff, 0x0008, 0x0002, 
0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0003, 0x0032, 0x0000, 0x000b, 0x0000, 0x0008, 0x000a, 
0x0000, 0x0066, 0x0075, 0x006c, 0x006c, 0x0000, 0x000b, 0x0000, 0x000b, 
0x0000, 0x000b, 0xffff, 0x000b, 0xffff, 0x000b, 0x0000, 0x0008, 0x0002, 
0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0008, 0x0002, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0008, 0x0002, 0x0000, 
0x0000, 0x0008, 0x0002, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x000b, 0x0000, 0x2834, 0x0000, 
0x043d, 0x0000, 
0
END

#endif    // Chinese (Traditional, Hong Kong S.A.R.) resources
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



#ifndef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 3 resource.
//


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#endif    // not APSTUDIO_INVOKED
```

Everything seems okay. The program compiles. GetLastError is 0. But the dialog just would not show up. The main window closes after clicking the Try button.

Really thank you for your comment and help. I rarely ask questions in here because most of the problems can be solved by Googling and tinkering. But this one is really difficult. I believe it should be very easy since making a dialog is one of the most basic things in GUI.

My programming experience mainly focuses on Java previously. I want to lament that Windows C is much harder since it seems that not much warning comes from compiler or IDE.

Comment: If you think you did everything OK, just launch [Spy++](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8d06750a-8d6c-4aca-9896-6ca49a631c07/where-can-i-get-microsoft-spy?forum=vcgeneral) tool and find your window there. In particular, you will see if it's visible or not. If it's visible and located outside of desktop, for example. You have tools to check this out.

Comment: Why have you neglected to check for errors? Calling `GetLastError` is not error checking. You must check return values. Where is your message loop?

Comment: @RomanR. Thanks for comment. The main window just closes after clicking the button. And I really can't see any dialog box.

Comment: You still have no error checking at all. And your message loop is wrong. Read the documentation for `CreateDialog`.

Comment: Test if `aDiag` is NULL and if yes, call `GetLastError()`

Comment: I have changed the code to check the error. aDiag is NULL but GetLastError messagebox shows nth. Thank you.

Comment: You really do need more error checking than that. You do need to fix your message loop. I think manuell has the answer as it happens. You also need to learn how to debug. Next step for you is to learn debugging skills.

Comment: @manuell Thanks for reply. The error still persists. I believe that if the break is important, my VS2012 should warn me about that when I compile. But no compiler complaint. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Don't post invalid code. Post the code you compile. There is a missing `}` in MainWinProc.

Comment: @manuell Thanks for reminding me that. Let me re-post my code.

Comment: You did not enclose `HWND aDialog = ..` with `{ }`-please see my edited answer. Try it and report results.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff Have tried your code. Still no dialog box. Very frustrated. I can play with JavaFX upside down, while I get bogged down by a Dialog Box in Windows C!

Comment: Your last chance is to upload a demo project somewhere for us to see it. I really can not see why it is not working-we "covered all bases". Hopefully you will find the time and will to do this. Best regards.

Comment: I venture to ask if anyone can show me finished code for a window which can show a modeless dialog by pressing a button. I have googling a lot but the examples are not very helpful.

Comment: @CheungBrian Finished/working code for showing a modeless dialog will not be very different from what you have (modulo the message pump loop)

Comment: Just one small remark, you should use _ltot_s instead of _ltoa_s, otherwise your code will not compile in Unicode mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enclose the above part of your code in `{ }` and tell us what happens.

You need to modify your `WM_COMMAND` code like this:

```
case WM_COMMAND:
    switch(LOWORD(wParam))
    {
    case LAUNCH_CONSOLE:
        {
            HWND aDiag = CreateDialog( (HINSTANCE) GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE),
                MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), 
                hwnd, 
                (DLGPROC) AboutDlgProc );

           if(aDiag == NULL)
           {
                MessageBox(hwnd, TEXT("Error"), TEXT("Error"), MB_OK);
                DWORD dwLE = GetLastError();
                TCHAR szLE[16];
               _ltoa_s(dwLE, szLE, 10 );
               MessageBox(hwnd, szLE, TEXT("Error"), MB_OK); 
           }
           ShowWindow(aDiag, SW_SHOW);
           break;
        }
    // other commands
```

---

Since you have asked a small demo application to demonstrate creation of a dialog on button click, here is the code you can copy/paste on empty `.cpp` file. **Just create your own dialog box in `.rc` editor:**

```
#include "resource.h"
#include <windows.h>

INT_PTR CALLBACK AboutDlgProc(HWND hwnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(Message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return TRUE;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch(LOWORD(wParam))
        {
            case IDOK:
                EndDialog(hwnd, IDOK);
                break;
            case IDCANCEL:
                EndDialog(hwnd, IDCANCEL);
                break;
        }
        break;
    default:
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        CreateWindowEx( 0, L"Button", 
            L"Click me!", 
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON,
            50, 20, 100, 50, 
            hwnd, (HMENU)8000, 
            GetModuleHandle(NULL), 0 );
        return (LRESULT)0;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch( LOWORD(wParam) )
        {
        case 8000:
            {
                HWND hDlg = CreateDialog( GetModuleHandle(NULL),
                    MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), 
                    hwnd,
                    AboutDlgProc );

                ShowWindow( hDlg, SW_SHOW );
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return (LRESULT)0;
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        return (LRESULT)0;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return (LRESULT)0;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, 
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG Msg;

    wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style         = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"Main_Window";
    wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Window Registration Failed!", L"Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }


    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
            WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
            L"Main_Window",
            L"Test application",
            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
            CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 240, 120,
            NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if(hwnd == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Window Creation Failed!", L"Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    while(GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }
    return Msg.wParam;
}
```

### EDIT-ADDED CODE FOR RESOURCE FILES:

`Resource.h` :

```
//{{NO_DEPENDENCIES}}
// Microsoft Visual C++ generated include file.
// Used by resource.rc
//
#define IDD_DIALOG1                     101

// Next default values for new objects
// 
#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
#ifndef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
#define _APS_NEXT_RESOURCE_VALUE        102
#define _APS_NEXT_COMMAND_VALUE         40001
#define _APS_NEXT_CONTROL_VALUE         1001
#define _APS_NEXT_SYMED_VALUE           101
#endif
#endif
```

`.rc` file:

```
// Microsoft Visual C++ generated resource script.
//
#include "resource.h"

#define APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 2 resource.
//
#include "afxres.h"

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#undef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// English (U.S.) resources

#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_ENU)
#ifdef _WIN32
LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US
#pragma code_page(1252)
#endif //_WIN32

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// TEXTINCLUDE
//

1 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "resource.h\0"
END

2 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "#include ""afxres.h""\r\n"
    "\0"
END

3 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "\r\n"
    "\0"
END

#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Dialog
//

IDD_DIALOG1 DIALOGEX 0, 0, 316, 180
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "Dialog"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK",IDOK,205,159,50,14
    PUSHBUTTON      "Cancel",IDCANCEL,259,159,50,14
END


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// DESIGNINFO
//

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
GUIDELINES DESIGNINFO 
BEGIN
    IDD_DIALOG1, DIALOG
    BEGIN
        LEFTMARGIN, 7
        RIGHTMARGIN, 309
        TOPMARGIN, 7
        BOTTOMMARGIN, 173
    END
END
#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED

#endif    // English (U.S.) resources
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



#ifndef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 3 resource.
//


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#endif    // not APSTUDIO_INVOKED
```

Comment: oh sorry, in fact I have done this already. My code should be corrected.

Comment: @CheungBrian: Please edit your code, so we can see what else can be done. By the way, your call to `CreateDialog` is not correct-you pass `HWND` as first parameter instead of `HINSTANCE`-compare my code snippet with yours.

Comment: @CheungBrian: Change `HWND aDiag = CreateDialog((HINSTANCE) GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_INSTANCE), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), NULL, (DLGPROC) AboutDlgProc);` to `HWND aDiag = CreateDialog((HINSTANCE) GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_INSTANCE), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), hwnd, (DLGPROC) AboutDlgProc);` and report your result. You are passing `NULL` as the parameter for **parent window**. Best regards.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff Seems pretty standard to use a NULL Parent for a Dialog.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff: I have tried it already. The problem is still there. Thank you.

Comment: @manuell: OK, pardon my ignorance-I am not that experienced. It is good to learn something new. It could be then the improper handling of the message loop. Thank you for the lesson. Best regards.

Comment: @CheungBrian: Modify your message loop like [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644996%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#modeless_box) and report your results ( declare a global variable that holds `HWND` of your dialog, and modify the message loop-do not forget to set that global variable to `NULL` in your dialog's `WM_CLOSE` and `IDCANCEL` handler ). Best regards.

Comment: @CheungBrian: Do as *manuell* suggested-modify your `WM_COMMAND` per his instructions. Only if that fails try my approach. Best regards.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff Trying to help, here, no pun intended, but the `IsDialogMessage` in only important for handling navigation keys (typically: Tab, Up, Down, Enter...) A missing IsDialogMessage does not explain a Dialog Box not showing up

Comment: @manuell: I entirely agree, the advice was given **before** I saw the missing `}break;` in his `WM_COMMAND` handler. Best regards.

Comment: @CheungBrian: Try the example from my edited answer. Just create your own `.rc` file and a dialog in it. Please report your results. Good luck. Best regards.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff Thanks for the code. Still nothing show up on my side. Is it due to property setting problem? Also, my computer runs on AMD. Will it be important?

Comment: @CheungBrian: To be honest, I do not know... What exactly is happening? Does the code compile without errors? Does main window shows up? Please be very specific, since this is very unusual. Best regards.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff Main windows does show up. But when I click the button, nth happens. Really thank you.

Comment: @CheungBrian: Hold on a second, I will try to create dialog programatically and edit my answer with that code. We will come to the bottom of this!

Comment: @CheungBrian: I can not create dialog programatically since the MSDN documentation offers no example. I will edit my answer with the code for `.rc` and `resource.h` files.

Comment: @CheungBrian: Done. Create those files, try again and report the result. Everything works fine on my machine, so if this does not work the problem is not in your code.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff GOOD! YOUR CODE WORKS! GREAT! WONDERFUL! Let me study more about your code! Really Thank you!!!

Comment: @CheungBrian: Great! than it is the `.rc` file that makes the problem. One last task that might solve your problem: Check **the ID value** of `LAUNCH_CONSOLE` and `ID_FILE_EXIT` and tell me if they are the same. If they are then it is the problem we seek. Best regards.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff Yes, the ID value is the culprit. They both have value 1234. Thousand tons of thank you to you.

Comment: @CheungBrian: So everything works now? Glad I could help. Best regards.

Answer (score 2):

The "main" `WM_COMMAND` processing is wrong, there is no break at the end of the switch.

So when a `WM_COMMAND` is processed with neither `ID_FILE_EXIT` or `LAUNCH_CONSOLE` in `LOWORD(wParam)`, the `WM_CLOSE` code is executed.

use:

```
case WM_COMMAND:
   switch(LOWORD(wParam))
   {
      case ID_FILE_EXIT:
         SendMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, NULL, NULL);
         break;
      case LAUNCH_CONSOLE:
         HWND aDiag = CreateDialog((HINSTANCE) GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_INSTANCE),
                                   MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), NULL,
                                   (DLGPROC),AboutDlgProc);
         ShowWindow(aDiag, SW_SHOW);
         break;
   }
   break; // <== breaking WM_COMMAND
```

EDIT: How to see the result of `GetLastError`

```
DWORD dwLE = GetLastError();
TCHAR szLE[16];
_ltot( dwLe, szLE, 10 );
MessageBox(hwnd, szLE, TEXT("Error"), MB_OK);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. The error still persists. I believe that if the break is important, my VS2012 should warn me about that when I compile. But no compiler complaint. Thank you for your response.

Comment: I see no reasons for a warning. Add that missing `break`. You said: "The main window closes after clicking the Try button." and the missing break explains it. Does your main windows still disapear with the break added?

Comment: Thank you for reply. The main window now stays in place. But the dialog still isn't showing. aDiag is still NULL.

Comment: GetLastError returns a DWORD, you can't just cast it to LPCSTR... If you don't know the basis of C programming, you will have a hard time. Wait for Updated answer.

Comment: hi manuell, thank you for your response. _ltot gets me compiler warning for being unsafe. And I use _ltota_s as suggested by the warning. And the GetLastError() is 0.

Comment: Ok, time to post the Ressource Template for the Dialog (located in your RC file). Also, please update question's code with you new code for displaying GetLastError

Comment: Try without the Media Player OCX. Remove the CONTROL.